# Concat the same series a bunch of times?

Tags: pandas

Let us say I have a series of

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
```

Is there a more efficient way of creating a million row df than

```
chamillion_row_df = pd.concat([a] * 1000000)
```

?

Comment: You have an extraneous closing brace `)`, should be just `chamillion_row_df = pd.concat([a] * 1000000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.tile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) for this:

```
pd.Series(np.tile(a.values, 1000000))
```

This will be much quicker than building a temporary list as a param to `pd.concat`

**timings**

```
In [42]:
%timeit pd.Series(np.tile(a.values, 1000000))
%timeit pd.concat([a] * 1000000)

100 loops, best of 3: 17.7 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 16.9 s per loop
```

So only ~1000x quicker using `np.tile`